# Foto intermedia en un TextView sin cortar el texto en dos

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-layout

Como puedo colocar texto alrededor de elementos en Android Estudio para se vea asi:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

O con el texto intermedio sin tener que picar el texto en dos asi :

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Por suerte alguien ya se planteó en su momento esta cuestión y creó una librería para resolvernos la vida al resto. Se llama FlowTextView y nos permite crear texto alrededor de una imagen.

Aquí lo tienes:
https://github.com/deano2390/FlowTextView

Tal y como se indica, añade la dependencia en gradle y úsala tal que así:

```
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:padding="10dip"
        android:src="@drawable/android"/>
```

Comment: Mucahs gracias Corpex !!